# jQuery validate: Validation still firing after the rule is removed (for select element)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am dynamically adding validation rules when a 'save' button is clicked - I am doing this for a text input and a select element:

> $("#my-txt").rules("add", { required:
>   true, messages: { required: "text
>   required"} });
>
> $("#my-ddl").rules("add", { required:
>   true, messages: { required: "selection
>   required"} });

After I add the rules I am manually triggering validation (`.valid()`) then removing the rules by doing  `.rules("remove")` on the elements. I do this because I want the errors to stay up until the user clicks 'save' again and validation is re-triggered.

This works fine and the errors are displayed correctly ... **BUT** ... while the error for the text input stays up no matter what, when I click on the drop down list the relevant error goes away (I can see display: none being injected in the span containing the error) independently of any selection (it goes away as soon as I click on the control, not when I tab off). I would expect the error for the drop down not to be hidden, same as the text input field.

The rule seems to be actually gone though, because if I go back and pick the default value on the select element (value="") it doesn't show the error message.

This has been puzzling me - I am trying to find a way to get both fields to work the same way.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the jquery-validate API again, I see there's no option to keep error shown and the difference in handling the display must be in the plugin code. Good luck fixing it. :)

Another way to fix this would be to manually save what jquery-validate add to your DOM, have it removed and re-append it yourself.

Finally, I prefer to see when my input is valid without having to reclick some buttons. Especially in the case of strange, complex password requirements.

Comment: thanks for your help - sounds like I am in trouble. I prefer that approach too (not having to click some button), unfortunately I am not writing requirements! ;)

Answer (score 0):

apart from removing this required through jquery.validation function, you can also remove the class "required" from your element. by doing this, jquery.validation will skip the element as it have no required class attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

call

```
$('#formid').removeData('validator')
```

This will remove validation for the form

Comment: Hai this is working fine...but what does mean 'validator'. this static or mean anything..?